# In Linux CLI, how can I list directory contents that show 12 hour mode for entries?

Tags: linux

In Linux how I can

ls - list directory contents,

That shows 12 hour mode PM:AM

Comment: This belongs on [su]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man ls` tells you that `ls` has a `--time-style=` option, which allows to specify a format as used in the `date` command. The man page for `date` shows various options, including %I for hour (0 - 12) and %p for the AM/PM indicator.

```
ls -l --time-style=+%D\ %I:%m\ %p
```

should do what you want.